# How do i send data to my tab bar - react native router flux

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

[image]
This is tab bar. In this notification section i want send counter every time new notification comes.

Here is the router component.  In notification_page scene i want to update the counter if there is notifications.

```
 <Router>
            <Stack key="root" hideNavBar={true}>
                <Scene key="lightbox"  lightbox >
                    <Scene key="drawer" drawer contentComponent={Drawer}>
                        <Scene key="tabbar"
                            showLabel={true}         
                        >
                            <Scene
                                key="landing_page"
                                component={Landing}

                                title={'Timeline'}
                            />
                            <Scene 
                                key="search_tab" 
                                component={Search} title="Search" 
                                renderLeftButton={() => this.renderLeftMenuButton()}
                            />
                            <Scene
                                key="tab3_1" 
                                component={CreateBlog} 
                                title="Create" 
                                renderLeftButton={() => this.renderLeftMenuButton()} 
                            />
                            <Scene 
                                tabBarLabel = {({ focused }) => (
                                <View>
                                <Icon
                                    size={40}
                                    name={`ios-notifications-outline`}
                                    text={`My Account`}
                                />
                            </View>
                            )} 
                                key="notification_page" 
                                component={Notifications} 
                                title="Notifications" 
                                renderLeftButton={() => this.renderLeftMenuButton()} 
                            />
                        </Scene>
                    </Scene>
                </Scene>
            </Stack>
        </Router>
```

Im using Redux for state management.

```
 <Provider store={store}>
     <View style={{flex:1}}>
          <RouterComponent  />
     </View>
 </Provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using redux or a helper method with state, whenever a new notification comes you can refresh the tab bar props with a counter using the actions method.

```
Actions.refresh({ counter: 1 }) // or whatever the counter is
```

- [React Native Router Flux Docs](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux)

Comment: how to get the props in my router.js file ??

Comment: I have the same issue with you, and any update on this @IshMan